# Redirecting output of pv for further processing

Tags: bash, redirect

I am trying to redirect the stderr of pv command and process it with tr like this:

```
(dd if=/dev/zero | pv -f -r > /dev/null) 2>&1 | tr "\r" "\n"
```

(dd is just an example) and this code is pretty fine (output is like

```
[ 189MB/s] 
[ 188MB/s] 
[ 186MB/s] 
[ 180MB/s]
```

) but the problem is that placing "|" or ">" to redirect it causes nothing flow to a destination file or pipe. I would like to process this output further but I have no idea why is that and how to fix that. Has anyone any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You are rooting `stdout` to `/dev/null`, then try to pipe it to `tr`. At which point the output is already lost. Get rid of the `> /dev/null`-part

Comment: Nope, I am redirecting stderr to (empty as you noticed) stdout and then to tr and this works fine. The problem is after tr, when I will try to pipe this example like: (dd if=/dev/zero | pv -f -r > /dev/null) 2>&1 | tr "\r" "\n" > somefile then error occur - the somefile proven to be empty.

Comment: I have just realized that removing this /dev/null redirection solves the problem with empty tr output somehow but then I have no way of filtering the input of pv command from the output of the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dd if=/dev/zero | pv -f -r 2> >(tr "\r" "\n") >/dev/null
```

EDIT:

Since OP wants to process the output from tr (stderr of pv), this can help:

```
dd if=/dev/zero | pv -f -r 2>&1 >/dev/null | tr "\r" "\n" | your_process_command
```

It redirects stderr to stdout & stdout to /dev/null. Thus bandwidth data is on stdout, which is then fed to tr.

EDIT2:
Sorry, the edit does not work either. I will try to find better way & update it....

Comment: Still can't redirect anything, your code (as it is or putted in to brackets) does not return any byte either on stdout or stderr.

Comment: 1. did you copy the above code line as is? 2. are you running bash or sh? because it [works on my system](http://www.buildsonmymachine.com/).

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Bash. As I said I also tried putting this into brackets but whatever I try the datas just disappear after doing any redirection.

Comment: By any chance, are you enclosing `dd if=/dev/zero | pv -f -r 2> >(tr "\r" "\n")` in parenthesis as: `(dd if=/dev/zero | pv -f -r 2> >(tr "\r" "\n")) >/dev/null` ??

Comment: No, this code doesn't works at all. Now I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing so let me explain that your code from the first post works in the way that I can see the output in the console (same as my code from a question) but I want to redirect what I can see on console to another process so I can process that output with others filters and use it in another script. But redirecting does not works.

Comment: Sorry, the edit does not work either. I will try to find better way & update it....